# "Unknown Encoder 'libx264'" error while using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, compilation, h.264, libx264

I have followed the guide given [here @ traq.ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu). And everything goes smoothly. But when I try to run a command with FFMPEG to convert something to h.264, I get the error:

> Unknown Encoder 'libx264'

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Please provide more detail. What is the format of input file? Did you try another file? Let us know what command you are trying.